# How to populate property of spring bean from static method

Tags: java, spring, static-methods

I would like to know, how can I populate spring bean property from static method. This is my example. I have ClassA and Utils with static method:

```java
    public class ClassA{
        private String name;
        private int age;
        
        //getters setters
    }
    
    public class Utils{
        static String getRandomName(){
            return "someRandomName"; //here is some logic returning random string
        }
    }
```

I would like to create bean from ClassA with usage of the Utils static method getRandomName. Like this:

```xml
<bean class="com.example.ClassA"
    p:name=//Utils.getRandomName()
    p:age="33"
/>
```

,but I do not know how to call static method from the application-context.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special value that produces random values. `random.value` will produce random alphanumeric strings. So your bean might look like:

```xml
<bean class="com.example.ClassA"
    p:name="${random.value}"
    p:age="33"
/>
```

If there is extra logic going on in your `getRandomName()`, then you can use Spring Expression Language ([SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions)) to execute expressions. For example:

```xml
<bean class="com.example.ClassA"
    p:name="#{ T(com.example.Utils).getRandomName() }"
    p:age="33"
/>
```